# Backbone & Jasmine spies: spying on a specific model trigger call

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

I'm trying to write a jasmine spy that listens for a backbone model event trigger.  The spy works, in a way: it spies on every `model.trigger` call.  Is there a way I can only have it look for a *specific* call?

For instance, if I want to spy on `@trigger 'error'`, but not `@trigger 'change'`, can I do so?  In my model below, the `@set` call also fires off a Backbone `change` event, which is firing my trigger spy and causing the test to fail.

Backbone model definition:

```
class @AdminDatasetModel extends Backbone.Model
  toggleEnabled: ->
    @set 'enabled', !@get('enabled')
    $.ajax
      url: "#{@urlRoot}/#{@get('id')}/enable"
      type: 'POST'
      data: 
        enabled: @get 'enabled'
      success: (data) =>
        PDLS.vent.trigger 'admin:itemToggled', @
      error: (jqXHR) =>
        @trigger 'error', 'There was a problem updating your dataset!'
```

Jasmine spec definition:

```
describe 'An admin dataset model', ->
    MOCK_GET_DATA =
        id: 1
        name: 'someName'
        enabled: true
        permissions:
            userId: 2

    MOCK_SUCCESS_DATA =
        succes: true

    MOCK_ERROR_DATA =
        error: true

    dataset = null

    beforeEach ->
        PDLS = new PDLSApp
        # Always return true for ajax requests, unless we specify otherwise
        spyOn($, 'ajax').andCallFake (params) ->
            params.success = MOCK_SUCCESS_DATA

        @triggerSpy = spyOn AdminDatasetModel.prototype, 'trigger'

        it 'should bubble up an error when appropriate', ->
            $.ajax.isSpy = false
            spyOn($, 'ajax').andCallFake (params) ->
                params.error MOCK_ERROR_DATA

            toggleSpy = spyOn AdminDatasetModel.prototype, 'toggleEnabled'
            dataset = new AdminDatasetModel(MOCK_GET_DATA)
            dataset.toggleEnabled()

            expect(toggleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
            expect(@triggerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith 'error', 'There was a problem updating your dataset!'
```

Comment: Yes - I only care about the error event, not whether trigger is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefer to do something like:

```
listener = jasmine.createSpy 'listener'
model = new AdminDatasetModel(MOCK_GET_DATA)
model.on 'error', listener
model.toggleEnabled()
expect(listener).toHaveBeenCalledWith 'There was a problem updating your dataset!'
```

instead of spying directly on `trigger`